# can I create two different prefixes point to the same namespace

Tags: c#

Consider the following class :

```
public class root {
    public string str;
}
```

Can I create an xml file as follows :

```
<root xmlns:pf1 = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:pf2 = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <str></str>
</root>
```

Thus I m trying to create two different prefixes for the same namespace. Also I am using XmlSerializer class and I have already done quite a bit of coding.

Comment: Well what have you tried, and what happened? (And are you using XmlDocument or LINQ to XML? Or built-in XML serialization?) I suspect you can construct such a document easily enough...

Comment: I am using built-in XML serialization as follows :   XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
 ns.Add("pf1", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
 ns.Add("pf2", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");   --> the output generated has only one prefix because both are referring to same uri. If the two uri's are different then the two prefixes appear in xml output

Comment: Are you committed to using the built-in serialization? That makes it harder to fine-tune exactly what XML is generated. (It's not clear why you *want* two aliases to the same namespace, mind you... it would help if you'd give more context.)

Comment: Actually I am to generate an output and as per the sample provided to me there are two prefixes, namely 'reqif'xhtml' and 'xhtml' both pointing to the same uri.

Comment: Well if you need to control the XML generated *precisely* (which is a very odd requirement, to be honest - anything taking your XML should care about the *semantics* rather than the aliases) then I'd suggest avoiding the built-in serialization.

Comment: Also I started with the XmlSerializer class and found most of the things falling in place. Now I have already written all the code using that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48225/discussion-between-user3282758-and-jon-skeet)

Comment: Sorry, I'm on a flaky 3G connection which would lead to a frustrating chat experience. If you absolutely *require* XML serialization then I suggest you edit that requirement into your question (which doesn't mention it anywhere); in that case someone else will have to help you. If you're able to use LINQ to XML to do it "manually" then that's a different matter.

Comment: Also I started with the XmlSerializer class and found most of the things falling in place. Now I have already written all the code using that
Hi, what other means would you suggest.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have modified my question. But I guess your suggestion is that I use LINQ to XML